# Means to or for

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "to" or "for" in my sentence? Is either "is" or "means" correct?

> In my opinion, marriage **is/means** giving up freedom **for/to** both partners.

Comment: Marriage means both partners giving up their freedom or means both partners give up their freedom. That would be the usual word order, for me.

Comment: What should I use with "mean to" or "mean for"?

Comment: Why do you suppose I rewrote it? In any event, how could it possibly be "to"? "freedom to marry", not freedom to persons. freedom for someone.

Comment: I mean if I use "Be".  "In my opinion, marriage is giving up freedom for/to both partners."

Comment: It does not matter if you use *is or means*.   "to both partners" does not work.  You want to use *to both partners*? The court issued arrest warrants **to** both partners.

Comment: No, I was asking if I should use a preposition. I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Marriage is/means** are both correct using your sentence structure, but 'freedom to' isn't.

because using **for** means, it's aimed for something. {e.g. good for your health} But you never say: {it's harmful **to** your health}.